# Reset WheelChooser widget initial values

Tags: flutter, dart

**Package:** https://pub.dev/packages/wheel_chooser

**Issue:**  The package doesn't have a key and/or a controller in order to reset or reassign the values.

**Question:** How do I implement a reset button for the WheelChooser widget? I'm currently reassigning the values to zero and navigating to the page with zero animation duration. The issue I have with this is that I also have a FutureBuilder showing a battery level, and this gets rebuilt each time the reset button is pushed. Is there any way to reset the values of this WheelChooser widget without having to refresh the entire page?

**Code example:**

```
              WheelChooser.integer(
              initValue: Clock().timerHours ?? 0,
              magnification: 1.7,
              listHeight: 150,
              itemSize: 30,
              squeeze: 0.75,
              listWidth: 100,
              onValueChanged: (hours) {
                setState(() {
                  Clock().timerHours = hours;
                });
                Clock.save();
              },
              maxValue: 23,
              minValue: 00,
              isInfinite: true,
            ),
```

**My Solution:** Refresh the page. i.e.

```
// The only way to reset the wheel values to zero is to
// reassign the init values and rebuild the page.
// TODO: Any other way of doing this?
        
if (Clock().timerHours != 0 ||
    Clock().timerMinutes != 0 ||
    Clock().timerSeconds != 0) {
      
      Clock().timerHours = 0;
      Clock().timerMinutes = 0;
      Clock().timerSeconds = 0;

      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
          PageRouteBuilder(
            pageBuilder: (_, __, ___) => Home(
              pageIndex: 3,
            ),
            transitionDuration: Duration(seconds: 0),
          ),
          (Route<dynamic> route) => false);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to :

- Create a custom StatefulWidget containing the WheelChooser and your algorithm to reset it
- In your algorithm, replace your pushAndRemoveUntil by a setState() to rebuild only this widget

Comment: I already have done option 1, the problem with option 2 is that setState will do nothing as `initValue` can not be reassigned once the widget is built.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to rebuild the widget or reload, you can use a controller and set the index of the wheel_chooser widget or the value with "jumpTo(double value)" or "jumpToItem(int item)". If you use a controller, like in the code below, DO NOT USE initValue().

```
`class _wheelpage extends State<wheelpage> {
    FixedExtentScrollController? controllerWC = FixedExtentScrollController();

child: WheelChooser.integer(
    onValueChanged: (value) {
        print('value: ' + avlue.toString());
        setState(() {
            savedValue = value;
        });
    },
    maxValue: 99,
    minValue: 0,
    itemSize: 100.0,
    controller: controllerWC,
);

setState((){
    print('restting wheel chooser');
    // USE BELOW TO SPECIFY VALUE
    // controllerWC?.jumpTo(0);
    // USE BELOW TO SPECIFY INDEX - 0 being min value
    controllerWC1?.jumpToItem(0);
});

}`
```